# How to input user parameters for an SSRS report?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, dynamics-crm-2011

I created a report using SSRS on VS2008 with a SQL query. My query uses two parameters to run :

I can input these parameters manually in Visual Studio, but how can I let the user input these parameters in CRM and then send them to my report ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the parameter visibility as "Visible" then the user will get the option to enter data at the top of the report. If the parameter type is correctly set then you will get the right editor for the type i.e. a calendar for a datetime type etc.